# Why don't certain NODE_OPTIONS environment variable values such as --use-openssl-ca propagate to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is the image showing VS Code environment variables captured with the Process Explorer vs the global environment variables.

As you can see, `NODE_OPTIONS` is present, but its value is empty in VS Code. It should have inherited it as it does for other environment variables.

[image]

What is going on with VS Code?

Also opened an issue here - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment in the github issue, this is a limitation from the runtime, unsupported options are:

- --use-bundled-ca
- --force-fips
- --enable-fips
- --openssl-config
- --use-openssl-ca

"The majority are supported with the exception of those which conflict with Chromium's use of BoringSSL."
source: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/environment-variables.md#node_options

**UPDATE**: to be more precise, as per the answer in another github issue, for packaged Electron applications (e.g. VS Code) only two values are allowed for NODE_OPTIONS, see below (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179712):

> when Electron application is packaged only the following two
> NODE_OPTIONS are allowed
>
> - --max-http-header-size
> - --http-parser"

Answer (score -1):

[As documented](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/environment-variables.md#node_options), only the following `NODE_OPTIONS` values are supported in packaged Electron apps (Ex. VS Code):

```
--max-http-header-size
--http-parser
```

---

Not relevant here, but just FYI: for non-packaged apps, the following are not supported for Electron in general since they conflict with Chromium's usage of BoringSSL:

```
--use-bundled-ca
--force-fips
--enable-fips
--openssl-config
--use-openssl-ca
```