# NODE_OPTIONS environment variable value not present in VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

The image below shows VS Code's environment variables captured with the Process Explorer (on the left side) and the global environment variables (on the right side).

As you can see, **NODE_OPTIONS** is present, but its value is empty in VS Code. It should have inherited it as it does for other environment variables, as you can see here:
[image]
Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
There is a similar issue, but the answer for that does not stand for the case of **max_old_space_size** as you can see there in the links:
[Why don't certain NODE_OPTIONS environment variable values such as --use-openssl-ca propagate to VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74103663/node-options-environment-variable-value-does-not-propagate-to-vs-code)

I also created an issue for this on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179712

Comment: did you restart VS Code after changing the system environment? (you need to) And does this VS Code process have any parent processes? If so, what do you see in the environment of the parent processes?

Comment: Yes I did restart VS code after it. No it does not have any parent processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in the github issue and as it turned out max_old_space_size setting is not supported. Answer on github (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179712):

> when Electron application is packaged only the following two
> NODE_OPTIONS are allowed
>
> - --max-http-header-size
> - --http-parser"