# Debugging Electron apps under symlinked directories in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-debugger

Normally, when debugging a Node.js application that's under a symlinked path, in VS Code I need to add this to my launch.json:

```json
"runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks"]
```

Without it, breakpoints open up in files in the wrong paths.

I need to do the equivalent when debugging an Electron application.  However, it seems that Electron isn't passing `--preserve-symlinks` to the instance of Node.js it launches.  I've also tried setting `NODE_OPTIONS`, but it had no effect.

### launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/electron/cli.js",
      "args" : ["."],
      "outputCapture": "std",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--preserve-symlinks"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: related (possibly answers your question?): [Why don't certain NODE_OPTIONS environment variable values such as --use-openssl-ca propagate to VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74103663/11107541)